# Disk I/O at limit with software raid

Tags: raid, hard-drive, software-raid, raid1, io

whenever I use rm or cp on a bigger file structure the disk i/o is going up to the top, but not with the focus on cp or rm, it is the software raid sync. My knowledge in this area is limited. The topics I found were about finding the source of it and nothing further. As I know it already here the question.

- Is this sort of behavior normal for a system raid?
- What can I do if I/O nice c3 is changing nothing due to the burst from the raid?

[image]
.

md2 is mounted with `nobarrier`

Drives: HGST HUS724020ALA640

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      523968 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      1936077760 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      16768896 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume this as normal behaviour.

As your `rm` process doesn't need much for iterating through the directory structure and delete files, for the underlying disks it causes more stress. This creates iowait and leads to this situation.

From your screenshot, i assume, that 37 MB/s write on a big directory structure (which means many IOPS) is quite fair for a 2 spinning-disk-array. As long as your throughput values regarding linear write and iops are ok, theres nothing to worry from my point of view.

For the not trivial task of limiting io see: [How to Throttle per process I/O to a max limit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/how-to-throttle-per-process-i-o-to-a-max-limit)
ionice is a approach, but will only become effective, if there is concurrent workload.

Comment: alright thanks. Do you have any idea/suggestion on what I could do to lower the usage. I don't mind if it takes 3 times as long. As stated above ionice failed. :(

Comment: This isn't a trivial question: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48138/how-to-throttle-per-process-i-o-to-a-max-limit for more details.

Comment: Anyway you should test your raid with dd, fio, bonnie... to see if it outputs, what you can expect from your setup, to totally exclude a misbehaviour.

Comment: I edited my answer with the additional information on throttling. Thanks for the accept/upvote!

Comment: Quick question. Does that mean ionice would slow it down once the jdb2 is going up. From what I noticed it doesn't slow down at all compared to rsync which is running before with c3 and being slowed down to tops 60% disk i/o usage. (98% without ionice setting)

Comment: Sorry, I cant answer this for sure as I'ver never used ionice, but I suggest you not try to limit jdb2, as it is the process, managing your filesystem journal. If you have 2 processes in userspace like rm and rsync, which do concurrent io, ionice is imho the way to give them priorities. If theres no concurrency, theres no need to limit anything from my point of view.

Comment: Some additional thoughts: Your rm looks like a backup/snapshot cleanup job - If you want to assure, that this one is not influencing you system, when additional load appears, limit this one with ionice, leave the other processes as they are. Regarding jdb2 there can be the following situations: If concurrent job is also intensive for filesystem, jdb2 will stay at high load, as journel needs updating, if its just a streamwrite in a single file, this job will get io advantage and the load of jdb2 will decrease.

Comment: I use rsnapshot for backups, meaning: 1. rsync, 2. rm 3. cp -> rsync is set to c3 in its config and rm+cp is running via a wrapper setting its ionice to c3. Still they both (rm and cp) hit the disk to 90% while other processes nearly freeze.

Comment: So I do use ionice for rm and cp but it doesn't work. Probably due to the case that the load isn't coming from rm or cp directly. I'll untick the solved for the moment, to see if others maybe know more and can give more useful information. Nothing personal or down voting.

Comment: No problem! One more question: is there any other process that would consume io? If not, its ok for rm & cp to use 100% - they should only get less priority, if other processes are requesting io - i think its working like nice on a regular process: the niced process will consume 100% cpu until another process requests cpu time, then it will be limited. If you intent to limit io usage globally for this (eg. to 50% for rm & 50% unused) you should rather stick with the cgroups solution than with ionice.

Comment: Unfortunately there are processes. That is the reason why I am looking for a solution. It is slowing down production processes. The application it self is nearly stopping. If we speak of 100% performance it is going down to 2-5% due to i/o wait. From 20 ms to ~450ms